# How to add a response from the server to a state with an object in react

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, server, response

I have user state with object:

```
{
'login': 'somelogin',
 'pass': 'somepass'
}
```

Using this data, I send a request and receive a response in the form of several keys

```
const res  = await post("/api/login", user);
```

Response comes an object:

```
{
'xsrf': 'qweqweqwe', 
'session': 'asdasdasd'
}
```

How do i merge the current state with the response
so that in the user state it would be like this:

```
{
'login': 'somelogin', 
'pass': 'somepass', 
'xsrf': 'qweqweqwe', 
'session': 'asdasdasd'
}
```

I can't think of what to write in the state setUser

something like:
setUser(user + res.data)

I don't know much about javascript and can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge multi object with below expression.

```
  const a = {'a': 1};
  const b = {'b': 2};

  const c = {...a, ...b};  // {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

In your case:

```
  const user = {
    'login': 'somelogin',
    'pass': 'somepass'
  };
  const response = {
    'xsrf': 'qweqweqwe', 
    'session': 'asdasdasd'
  };

  const result = {...user, ...response};
```

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)